# How to merge 2D number array based on the first items of inner sub array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given 2d-array ***[ [ 2, 12 ], [ 3, 12 ], [ 3, 15 ], [ 5, 15 ] ]***.

I would like to check whether the first element of subarray is equal to the neighbour's first element. And if they are equal, I would like to sum their second elements and replace these 2 with the new array.

So the output must be: ***[ [ 2, 12 ], [ 3, 27 ], [ 5, 15 ] ]***.

Thank you!
I've tried the regular for loop, but it throws the TypeError saying it can't access the value of undefined

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (arr[i][0] === arr[i+1][0]) console.log( arr[i] );
}

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:5:29
at Script.runInContext (vm.js:74:29)
at Object.runInContext (vm.js:182:6)
at evaluate (/run_dir/repl.js:133:14)
at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/run_dir/repl.js:116:5)
at ReadStream.emit (events.js:180:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:261:11)
at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:218:10)
at fs.read (fs.js:2124:12)
```

Comment: what if all subarrays have the same first element or there are more then 2 subarrays with the same first elment ?

Comment: Eventually `arr[i+1]` will index beyond the end of your array returning undefined. Maybe you could change your loop condition: `i < arr.length -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Check if the `accumulator`'s last item has the same `key` as the current item in context. If yes, sum the `value` parts. Else, push the item to `accumulator`

```js
const data = [[2, 12], [3, 12], [3, 15], [5, 15]];

const newArray = data.reduce((acc, a, i) => {
  if (i > 0 && a[0] === data[i-1][0])
    acc[acc.length-1][1] += a[1]
  else
    acc.push(a);
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(newArray)
```

The above logic using ternary and [comma operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

```js
const data = [[2, 12], [3, 12], [3, 15], [5, 15]];

const newArray = data.reduce((acc, a, i) => (
    i > 0 && a[0] === data[i-1][0]
     ? acc[acc.length-1][1] += a[1]
     : acc.push(a), acc), [])

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You coud reduce the array and take a helper variable for the last pushed element of the result set;

```js
var array = [[2, 12], [3, 12], [3, 15], [5, 15]],
    grouped = array.reduce((last => (r, a) => {
        if (last && last[0] === a[0]) {
            last[1] += a[1];
        } else {
            r.push(last = a);
        }
        return r;
    })(), []);

console.log(grouped);
```